# What is the best way to close a MySQL connection in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I developed a simple app that allows users to input data in a local database, but eventually it will have many simultaneous connections in a production environment, which includes data being stored in a data center.

Right now my app can read (from two different tables) and write in one of them, but it has *at least* one problem: I close the connection right after a user has ended submitting data for one employee, and I actually want to the app to allow the input for many of them in a single session, so the flow would be:

> (1) . user enters the app  > (2) . user saves an employee > (3) . the
>   app informs the user about the result of the entry (might be
>   duplicates value for several fields which would show an error, a
>   successfully saved employee message, etc) [here I close the connection] > (4) . goes back to ***(2)***, if the user chooses to, and I *try* to open it again.

---

> EDIT:
>   The error I get when I try to enter a new user right after I close the connection is `"connection must be valid and open"`

I'm expecting that a Singleton object handles this, but is not actually doing it.

```
    private MySQLDataAccess()
    {
        this.openConnection();
    }

    private MySqlConnection Connection;

    private static MySQLDataAccess instance;

    public static MySQLDataAccess GetInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new MySQLDataAccess();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

So, my question is...

Should the app close the connection with the db right after the application ends? this might include a user that saves more than 50 employees in one sit.

Or should I close the connection every time a user is saved, and then opening it again to save a new user? (this is what I'm *trying* to do right now, but I'm not doing it properly)

Comment: If you're deploying this in IIS, it will use connection pooling, so your app won't be opening and closing connections directly anyway. So I would just use `using` statements to create and dispose of MySqlConnection objects as you need them. The actual opening and closing will be handled by the connection pool. (N.B. "Should the app close the connection with the db right after the application ends" doesn't make a lot of sense in a web environment. Connections are made separately each time a HTTP request fires.)

Comment: If you have a lot of things to do at the same time, it would be ideal to create a MySqlTransaction and close the connection right after.

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you explain with more details, please?

Comment: Open connection -> execute query -> close connection

Comment: @Djuro that's exactly what I'm doing right now, is not working well for me

Comment: @ADyson thanks, I'll look into it. I'm deploying this in IIS express, and the production environment has IIS 7, will this method work ok with IIS 7?

Comment: What isn't working well for you?  What makes you think it isn't working well? How do you determine that?

Comment: by "this method" you mean the one I suggested? Yes. ADO.NET has connection pooling and the MySQL connector supports it. I suggest you read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html

Comment: I think ADyson means that the .Net Framework/.Net Core has connection pooling (and most ADO Providers following this pattern), and is (mostly) unrelated to IIS.

Comment: @RobertMcKee yes, sorry that's a better use of terminology

Comment: @RobertMcKee please check the edit

Comment: That would indicate that you've closed the connection and you haven't reopened it (or better.. just create a new connection) before attempting to execute something.  We would need to see the rest of your code, but you really should NOT be using a singleton. That'll be terrible.

Comment: @newbie the "best" way is the one shown in all tutorials and courses - just create the connection inside a `using` block and the connection will be closed and disposed when execution leaves the block. **DON'T** use a singleton connection, this can only cause performance degradation due to lock accumulation and blocking with other connections

Comment: @RobertMcKee so, shouldn't just one instance of a single object handle the database connection(s)?

Comment: @newbie No.  Create new instances of MySqlConnection whenever you want to access the database.  Usually this is done in say a data access layer (DAL), or in an ORM like entity framework.

Comment: OK @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, I'll change my implementation details, of course I've seen tutorials about this, but I thought that using "using" was only a way to not import the class itself (from a java background)

Comment: @newbie ADO.NET uses connection pooling when available, which means opening a new costs nothing - the provider will simply pick an available connection from the pool. Connector/NET does provide connection pooling. There's no good reason to use a singleton connection

Comment: @newbie "shouldn't just one instance of a single object handle the database connection"... no, it shouldn't. It's unnecessary. Again, read about how connection pooling works. Your code is not really in charge of opening and closing the connections. When you "open" a connection in your code it actually just takes a connection from the pool which, more than likely, is already open.

Comment: ok @RobertMcKee ty very much, I will do that.

Comment: `that using "using" was only a way to not import the class itself` you're talking about the `using` directive. All ADO.NET examples and tutorials show the `using` statement.

Comment: "I thought that using "using" was only a way to not import the class itself"...no, it's a good way to ensure that objects are disposed of properly, without the programmer forgetting, and without danger of things happening at the wrong time. It's highly recommended to use it with any Disposable object. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement and https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/the-using-statement-in-C-Sharp/ for an intro. P.S. don't confuse the `using` _statement_ with the _directive_ of the same name.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, ad ADyson yeah, I understand that now, I was mixing those two concepts, as far as I know, java doesn't have a using statement, so I didn't know that it existed in c#, and that it was the same thing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best practice is to not keep connections open (or even re-used) for more than one "unit of work". The most effective way to do that is with `using` blocks:

```
using(MySqlConnection conn = ...)
{
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = ...)
    {
        // open connection
        // execute command
        // close connection (optional - the connection will be closed when 
        //                   it gets disposed, but it's more explicit this way)
    }
}
```

The connection will be closed automatically even if there is an exception.

Also, don't do any retrying that requires user input within the blocks (e.g. "you've entered a duplicate value - try again"). If you get an error, dispose of the connection, get new inputs, then create a new connection and try again.

Comment: I personally prefer going through the connection factory whenever possible so that I can swap out providers quickly, but that is a decent start.

Comment: "swap out providers quickly" how often do you think that could happen?

Comment: Often enough.  One of the things you need to do to get glimpse working as a profiler (or atleast you did), was to swap out the stock provider with one that had instrumentation in it.  I've also swapped out the stock Sql provider with a custom one that handled transient connection problems transparently in some projects (great for migrations to azure/cloud).  So often it's not switching the database, it's literally switching to a provider that has more functionality than the default ones from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Or use a connection factory, assuming your connection information in your web.config:

```
var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName];
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(settings.ProviderName);
using (var conn = factory.CreateConnection())
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
  conn.ConnectionString = settings.ConnectionString;
  conn.Open();
  ...
  conn.Close();
}
```

More often than not however, I'm just using Dapper on the DbConnection, which abstracts away most of the pain of mapping and opening/closing for me.